# 2 way database encryption

Tags: mysql, database, encryption

I am looking to implement 2 way encryption on some MySQL databases and possibly other types of DBs in the future.  However I need to have the encryption NOT be handled by either the webserver or the database.  Rather I am looking for software that I can install in between the webserver and the database that will handle this.  Any recommendations on software that can handle this?

Also the database will already have an encrypted file system and connections through ssl, so those parts of the equation are already handled.

Comment: If all access to the DB is done through the encryption layer, you haven't actually added much security.  Attackers can also use the encryption layer.  Also, that would make indexed queries impossible.

Comment: It seems handling the encryption and decryption at the webserver or database would be less secure than using a remote crypto service to handle it.

Comment: No.  A remote service can't tell whether it's decrypting data for your application or for an attacker.

Comment: Security is not simply a matter of slapping encryption in random places.  You need to figure out who you're defending against and how you will store keys.  Read http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/27/keep-it-secret-keep-it-safe.aspx

Comment: So in your opinion, what would you recommend for protection against sql dumps?

Comment: Strong (network-level and application-level) access control for your database.  It would help to make a proxy with its own stronger authentication, then firewall the database to be inaccessible from everywhere else.

Comment: This is a good idea for preventing access, however in the event that someone gets in and has the data.  If I am not using a service to handle encryption, where would be the best place to handle the encryption?  Webserver or Database?  Assuming the key is not stored locally on either.

Answer (score 0):

If it's purely transport encryption you are looking for you could tunnel your connection through a VPN, or SSH. Both would be independent of the database and webserver.

Comment: Transport encryption is already handled as the last sentence states.  I need something to handle the decryption of the data at rest.